# If $b$ is a divisor of $a^2 - a + 1$, can $a$ be a divisor of $b^2 - b + 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

I observed that for $a > 1$, if $b$ is a divisor of $a^2 - a + 1$ then $a$ is not a divisor of $b^2 - b + 1$. This implies that their divisors are mutually exclusive. Is this true in general?

$$
b \mid a^2 - a + 1 \implies a \nmid b^2 - b + 1
$$

I have verified this for $a \le 10^9$.

Comment: This is half of Theorem 3 in W. H. Mills' [A system of quadratic Diophantine equations](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/pacific-journal-of-mathematics/volume-3/issue-1/A-system-of-quadratic-Diophantine-equations/pjm/1103051516.full) (the other half being OEIS [A101368](http://oeis.org/A101368)).

Comment: The phrasing "divisors are mutually exclusive" should be clarified. For example, $3^3 - 3 + 1, 5^2 -  5 + 1 $ both have a common divisor of 7.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We restrict our attention to positive integers.

This is a Vieta jumping solution, where we use the existing solution set to find another solution set, and hope to reach the base case or find a contradiction.

We call $(a, b)$ a valid set if $ a \geq b > 0$, $a \mid b^2 - b + 1, b \mid a^2 - a + 1$, and $ a > 1$.
There is a solution $ (1,1)$, which isn't a valid set because $ a \not > 1 $.
We will show that there are no valid sets.

Proof by contradiction. Suppose we have a valid set. Let $ ac = b^2 - b + 1 $.

We will show that $(b, c)$ is also a valid set by checking that it satisfies the conditions.

- If $b = 1$, then $ a \mid b^2 - b + 1 = 1$ gives us $ a =1$, so $ b > 1$.
- $ b^2 - b + 1 = ac \equiv 0 \pmod {c}$.
- Since $ac = b^2 - b + 1 > 0$, hence $ c > 0$.
- Since $b^2 > b^2 -b + 1 = ac $, and $ a \geq b$, hence $ b > c $. (This is stronger than the $ b \geq c$ that we need, and we will use this subsequently.)
- $ ac \equiv 1 \pmod{b}$, so $ a^2(c^2 - c + 1 ) \equiv 1 - a + a^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{b}$. Dividing out by $a^2 $ (Since $ \gcd(a, b) = 1$) gives us $ c^2 - c + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{b}$,

We can repeat the above process to get strictly smaller valid sets (Since $ b > c$).
Let this chain be $ a_1 = a, a_2 = b, a_3 = \frac{a_2^2 - a_2 + 1 } { a_1} , \ldots, a_{i+1} = \frac{ a_i ^ 2  - a_i + 1 }{ a_{i-1}} $. We have:

- $ a_i > a_{i+1} > a_{i+2} $
- $a_{i} a_{i+2} = a_{i+1}^2 - a_{i+1} + 1 $

However, there is no strictly decreasing chain of positive integers. Hence, we have a contradiction.

---

It's not immediately clear to me how to deal with the negative integers. Note that several of the inequalities need not be true.
We have the 3 chains

- $1, 1, 1, \ldots$
- $ 1, -1, 1, -1, \ldots $
- $ - 1, -1, -1, \ldots $
  I'm not sure if there are other solutions.

Comment: Won't this argument supposedly also work on $a\mid b^2+b+1$ and $b\mid a^2+a+1$? But then the pair $(61,13)$ is a solution.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Not quite, but that's because I'm still missing a part that talks about when $a_n = 1$ and explaining what happens there. (am working on this, haven't figured it out yet). In your case, we get the sequence $ 61, 13, 3, 1, 1, 3, 13, ..... $

Comment: Yes. This chain construction is the same as that in dxiv's link, and the terminal $a_n=1$ seems to be the hardest part. Note the $c<b$ argument can be simplified by noting $ac=b^2-b+1<b^2$ and $c<b$ directly follows.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Ah interesting. I thought that terminate part would work out easily, so I wrote up the rest. Let me see what I can do about it.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Alright, this should be fixed (for positive integers).